# Assigning dynamic number of variables to dataframe column values?

Tags: pandas

So I'm pulling in a dataframe and I need to assign the column values to a variable for later use. Normally, I'd do this by just doing:

```
x_1 = df_cc.iloc[0,3]
x_2 = df_cc.iloc[1,3]
x_3 = df_cc.iloc[2,3]
```

However, I'm trying to make my code more dynamic and the original dataframe may have more or less than the three column values I want to assign a variable to. Is there a way to create more or less variables dependent on the number of lines in my dataframe?

Comment: `x1,x2,x3 = df_cc.iloc[:2,3]`?

Comment: But what if I need x1, x2, x3, x4, and x5?

Comment: Then use a list.